# how to display a multi-dimensional matrix in opencv

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, matrix

i want to display a multi-dimensional matrix B(1000,1000,3) in opencv to see the values of this matrix at each (i,j,k) index
here is my declaration and how i fill this matrix

```
 Mat   image1 = imread("C://images//PolarImage300915163358.bmp"); // image 800*600
    int dim1[3] = {1000,1000,3};
    Mat B(3,dim1, CV_64F, Scalar::all(-1)); 
    for (int j1 = 0; j1 < 800; j1++)
      {
       for (int j2 = 0; j2 < 600; j2++)
        {
         jj1 =  round( ((double)phi/stepphi)+701.0);
         jj2 =  round( ((double)theta/steptetha)+501.0);

         B.at<double>(1199-jj1,jj2,0) =  image1.at<double>(j1,j2);
         B.at<double>(1199-jj1,jj2,1) =  image1.at<double>(j1,j2);
         B.at<double>(1199-jj1,jj2,2) =  image1.at<double>(j1,j2); 
      }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please use proper variable names so readers know what you mean? `jj1` `jj2` `B`

Comment: yes i will take that into account

Comment: What's wrong with [cout](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#output-formatting)? And why have you tagged this question MATLAB?

Comment: i don ' t kinow how to use it when we have a muti-dimensional array for matlab it was suggested by stackoverflow, and i could not pose the question if it was not added to the tags list

Comment: I've removed the MATLAB tag. Exact instructions on using `cout` are in the link I gave in my previous comment. Please learn how to punctuate your sentences; I had to read your comment several times trying to figure out why you had a "multi-dimensional array for matlab".

Comment: i don't speak english very well that is why